# Content profile vs profile

Tags: nodes, users

I am confused as whether there is even a need for me to enable content profile, I mean you can use profile of drupal that has the ability to enable extra fields and all.Whileas content profile only has one field, Name, Bio ....

Answer (score 4):

With the core user profile you can have just one profile.

[Profile2](http://drupal.org/project/profile2) gives you the permission to create different profile type and with the permission you can relate it to the role.
Every profile can have different fields.
Quick example:

Let's say you have a football website, so you have different profiles for different role player like goalkeeper wing, midfilder etc...

You create one profile per each role with different fields with Profile2
goalkeeper: height, gloves size etc...

Wing: first foot, side, speed etc...

You go to people->permission->role and you create a role per each role player and then you give the permission to a role for the related Profile so user with wing role can use the wing profile.

In the core user account you can create a field "Role player" (a radio button in this case is better)

Goal Keeper | Wing etc...

Then you will use "[Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules/)" to create the rule

**React on event** = After saving a new user account

**Condition** = data comparision (you should look for you field "role player" in core user account)

**Action** = Add user role (you can select the relative role)

Automatically the role is assigned.

Comment: Your welcome, I hope this helps you :)